# Word for an Origin and Destination without regard for route

Tags: vocabulary

I'm looking for a word that describes an origin and destination, regardless of the route taken.

The words I've come up with so far, route, trip, travel, etc. all imply a specific set of directions.

To clarify: I'm interested in a noun that describes a set of two points, one of which is an origin, and the other a destination. It does not care about how, or even if, the travel is made.

Additional clarification: The motivation for the question is the naming of a software class. This class holds information about traveling one point to another. Those travels can occur along multiple routes (another class), hence the desire for a path-agnostic noun.

Despite the original motivation, I am now very curious for a word to describe this, regardless of the software development context. The best I've found so far is 'commute.'

As a thought... I'd imagine the airline industry must have a term for this. Travel from Hong Kong to New York - one route may have a layover, another may be direct, though the origin and destination are the same.

Comment: It seems like anything can "suggest" as set of directions since you cannot have an origin and destination without travelling...I agree with @cornbreadninja麵包忍者 that trip and travel both minimize the association. Is this for software or UI design?

Comment: It is indeed for software design. I'm struggling to find the least ambiguous term for an object.

Comment: In that case, you might consider "vector".

Comment: I had always seen this referred to as simply ["origin-destination"](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/37970) (e.g. a set of points whose routes/transit times vary) but I'd be quite interested to see if anyone comes up with something better.

Comment: There's 67,300 hits in google for: `lineBegin` and `lineEnd`

Comment: My understanding, and usage, of vector has always been in instances of angular direction and velocity. But I suppose it could work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider *[termini](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/termini#Noun)*, which is a plural form of *[terminus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terminus#Noun)*, which is an end point (either end) of a route.  Also *[terminals](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terminal#English)*, like stations where service begins or ends, and *[endpoints](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/endpoint#Noun)*, either of the two points at the end of a line segment, and *[waypoints](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waypoint#Noun)*,  mapped reference points on a route.

Answer (score 4):

What about the word [journey](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/journey)

> 1. an act or instance of traveling from one place to another

**Edit:**
If you're looking for the start and end locations, the term *node* is generally used.  Since maps are structured using trees, they simply incorporated their naming scheme.

**Edit 2:**
I would say the collection of start and end points could be called the *path*.  While there may be points between, this would be the general gist of your vector.

Answer (score 4):

- ***node-pair***
- ***startpoint-endpoint (pair)***
- ***city-pair*** / ***airport-pair*** / ...

I believe *city-pair* is common parlance in the airline industry.

Answer (score 2):

*Waypoint* might fit, especially if the data is geographic.

In graph theory, you would simply call them *S* and *T*.  *S* for *source*, and *T* either for *target* or because it comes after *S* in the alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with the listed answers such as waypoint, node and terminals. However, itinerary might also suit your needs. It indicates travel from A to B, without directly indicating how/when/where. It does however indicate that this information is to be found within the itinerary.